# Why did they choose The Doctor to produce a new soldier?

Tags: doctor-who

In the popular episode *The Doctor's Daughter* of *Doctor Who*, The Doctor was a stranger to the soldiers. Why did they use him instead of themselves to create a new soldier?

While newly produced ones' memory were fully written in favor of their faction, the corruption was also a possibility. That's why, the commander locked The Doctor's Daughter with The Doctor later in the episode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Everyone gets processed.

Remember, the people that found the newcomers were basic footsoldiers.
Besides, there are only two groups of people on Messaline: the humans and the Hath.
The Doctor and co obviously aren't Hath, therefore they must be on the side of the humans, and thus they get processed just like everyone else.

It wasn't until much later that they were discovered to be "pacifist stock", resulting in Cobb locking up Jenny along with the Doctor and Donna. Up until that point there had been no reason to suspect any kind of "corruption" though, especially given Jenny's "G.I. Jane" attitude and the Doctor's help in locating a previously-hidden route to the Source.

Basically, it was just a matter of following orders ("Everyone gets processed") that had never accounted for the possibility of outsiders, let alone such "pacifist stock" as the Doctor, as there never had been anyone but the two factions on the planet. Good soldiers don't question orders, though, especially as they had no reason to do so here.

The only reason, I suspect, that Donna and Martha weren't "processed" as well is because of the Hath attack just after Jenny stepped out.

Comment: Fine. The last sentence addressed the issue with first sentence, too. :)